# Change name of certain character and location in filenames

Tags: r, regex

I want to change one of the _ to another character, for example to -, the reason is there are problems reading in these filenames. I want a to become like b. So I want to change the second last underscore(_), how to specify this in an efficient way?

`gsub("_", "-")`, it must also be specified to a certain location.

```
a <- c("2018-01-09_B2_HILIC_POS_123_-14b_090.mzML", "2018-01-09_B2_HILIC_POS_243_-12a_026.mzML", "2020-01-09_B2_HILIC_POS_415_893a_059.mzML", "2020-01-18_B3_HILIC_POS_LV7001248356_040.mzML")
b <- c("2018-01-09_B2_HILIC_POS_123--14b_090.mzML", "2018-01-09_B2_HILIC_POS_243--12a_026.mzML", "2020-01-09_B2_HILIC_POS_415-893a_059.mzML", "2020-01-18_B3_HILIC_POS_LV4004365711_040.mzML")
```

Comment: How do you know where the change has to be made? is it random or does it follows a pattern? if it has some kind of pattern, then maybe regex within gsub could solve your problem

Comment: @ Aaron Parrilla the second last_ need to bechanged! but the position can vary. But its always a number before and a number or_ after...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
sub("_(?=[^_]*_[^_]*$)", "-", a, perl=TRUE)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/6j2ikK/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^_]*                    any character except: '_' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^_]*                    any character except: '_' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

See [R proof](https://tio.run/##dc5NC4JAFIXhfb9ikBYaTtx7Z7QZSAIjSDCSvjZRF412BWG06c9PGi2EavOuHg6ndq4UYylOvkeARgJKsJwSz7M8m3KxXDOSYom6YrAwvD4XuReKv5h0i6lkoLiDCX5hjREbqxoc2S@MhlPVwfluBICkjYpiBv25EvTuj8r32J8k@yMfBvxuP2iXZJMyFLdzfUk2q@0scO4F):

```r
a <- c("2018-01-09_B2_HILIC_POS_123_-14b_090.mzML", "2018-01-09_B2_HILIC_POS_243_-12a_026.mzML", "2020-01-09_B2_HILIC_POS_415_893a_059.mzML", "2020-01-18_B3_HILIC_POS_LV7001248356_040.mzML")
sub("_(?=[^_]*_[^_]*$)", "-", a, perl=TRUE)
```

**Results**:

```
[1] "2018-01-09_B2_HILIC_POS_123--14b_090.mzML"    
[2] "2018-01-09_B2_HILIC_POS_243--12a_026.mzML"    
[3] "2020-01-09_B2_HILIC_POS_415-893a_059.mzML"    
[4] "2020-01-18_B3_HILIC_POS-LV7001248356_040.mzML"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one base R option using `sub` :

```
sub('(.*)(_)(.*_.*)$', '\\1-\\3', a)
#[1] "2018-01-09_B2_HILIC_POS_123--14b_090.mzML"    
#[2] "2018-01-09_B2_HILIC_POS_243--12a_026.mzML"    
#[3] "2020-01-09_B2_HILIC_POS_415-893a_059.mzML"    
#[4] "2020-01-18_B3_HILIC_POS-LV7001248356_040.mzML"
```

Here we divide data into 3 groups -

The 1st group is everything until second last underscore which is captured using `(.*)` and used as a backreference (`\\1`).

The 2nd group is second last underscore which us replaced with `-`.

The 3rd one is everything after second last underscore which is captured using `(.*_.*)` and used as a backreference (`\\3`).